# Merging two lists into a new list, index to same index, while not adding to length

Tags: java, list, hashmap

Im trying to merge two lists into a new list with all the values of the two staying at the same  index as the originals, while not adding to the new list length.
List A contains one number at random indexes, some are null, numbers are between 1-3.
List B contains numbers 123 on all indexes. 
I tried using a for loop and list add, but then it gave me a indexoutofbounds because it seems that list add pushes the content of the list when it adds a value. Im now trying to use hashmap:

lists:

```
Int arraylength = 10;

ArrayList<Integer> mergeballs = new ArrayList<>(arraylength); // merging list A
// contenent: null,3,null,null,2,3,null,1,null,2

ArrayList<Integer> hats = new ArrayList<>(arraylength); // merging list B
//contenent: 123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123,123


ArrayList<Integer> hatsMerged = new ArrayList<Integer>(arraylength); // A & B merged
for (int o = 0; o < stickarray.length; o++) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer (arraylength);
    map.put(o, hats.get(o) + mergeballs.get(o));
    hatsMerged.add(o,map.get(o));
    System.out.print(hatsMerged.get(o));
}
```

With this code im also getting a index out of bounds and hats and mergeballs are getting summarized, which I do not want. I want it to be: 123,1233,123,123,1232,1233,123,1231,123,1232

How can I do this? and is hashmap the best option?

Comment: How can the two lists keep items at the same index once merged? Once merged, the merged list will contain the items of both lists, so how item 1 of list B, could be kept at that index once merged with list A which also has an item 1?

Comment: What is the point of a list containing the same value on all indexes ? Plus, I agree with Edwin Dalorzo, the question makes no sense as far as I undestand it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach to do what you seem to be asking for. Ignore `null`, convert the `int` to a `String` - then concatenate the other `int` to the `String` and convert back to an `int` for storage in the merged `List<Integer>`.  Something like,

```
public static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        Integer val = a.get(i);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (val != null) {
            sb.append(val);
        }
        Integer bv = b.get(i);
        if (bv != null) {
            sb.append(bv);
        }
        try {
            al.add(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return al;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123,
            123, 123);
    List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(null, 3, null, null, 2, 3, null, 1,
            null, 2);
    List<Integer> merged = merge(a, b);
    System.out.println(merged);
}
```

Output is (the requested) -

```
[123, 1233, 123, 123, 1232, 1233, 123, 1231, 123, 1232]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not use a hashmap . You can just check for the null value and substitute with zero and add and hence merge the values between the two lists. You can avoid 2 get calls by assigning `mergeballs.get(0)` to an Integer local variable and use it in the conditional expression.

```
    Integer result;
    ArrayList<Integer> hatsMerged = new ArrayList<Integer>(arraylength); // A & B merged
    for (int o = 0; o < arraylength; o++) {
        result = ((mergeballs.get(o) == null) ? 0 : mergeballs.get(o)) + ((hats.get(o) == null) ? 0 : hats.get(o));
        hatsMerged.add(result);
        System.out.print(hatsMerged.get(o));
    }
```